# Does Firebase accept websocket

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

I am create my own backend using `Firebase Admin Sdk`, which i deploy to firebase cloud function, now, i want to implement websocket for 1 to 1 chat.

i dont want to `streambuilder` of flutter to start listerning to changes in a collection, i want all should be coming from the backend..

i will also appreciate if i can see a sample code in combining user id as the connect room of in flutter i use this

```
var peerid = auth.currentUser!.uid.hashCode < data['id'].hashCode
    ? auth.currentUser!.uid + '_' + data['id']
    : data['id'] + '_' + auth.currentUser!.uid;
```

to create a chat room, so how use this with websocket, so they should be listern base on the peerid

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Cloud Functions are not long-running.  They have a [maximum execution times](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas#time_limits).

That said, you are looking to build a chat system. Why not use the technology within Firebase designed specifically for that use case: [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database), where the "realtime" part is that the Firebase Client SDK offers its own built-in realtime listener to the database?  This is equivalent to websockets....but you don't have to do the ugly work of maintaining websockets!